# How can I embed every image in a directory in an HTML page using Django?

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to create image tags for every file in a directory located in `static` in my Django project. What is the best way to do this? I suppose I could write pure python with `os.listdir` and just use strings to concatenate the image tags together using the filenames, but I'm sure there's a better way using Django's HTML formatting. Haven't been able to figure it out.

Example: In a folder there is `img1.jpg` and `img2.jpg`.

How can I produce:

```
<img src="img1.jpg" alt="img1.jpg" height="100px" width="100px">
<br>
<img src="img2.jpg" alt="img2.jpg" height="100px" width="100px">
<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear about what you're looking for, but from

> create image tags for every file in a directory located in static

I'm assuming that you're looking to load image using the `{% static %}` tag:

```
{% load static %}
...
<img src="{% static 'path_to_image' %}" alt="img1.jpg" height="100px" width="100px">
<!-- Watch out the single and double quotes -->
```

Do remember to include this in your `settings.py`:

```py
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), // or wherever you put your static files
]
```

I think it's now automatic, but check your `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Compared to hard-coded paths like `C:/foo/baz/bar/`, it's better to load static tags because it always works on different platforms as every operating system has its own way to handle files, which I hope answers your question.

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful, but I'm looking to do this but for every file in a directory (e.g. ```static/images/```). Is it possible to use a for loop and produce the img tag as you put but for every image in the folder?

Comment: I'm unsure about what you mean by `every file in a directory` because, since I've done it, you don't need to pass the static files in the context to parse it in the HTML

Comment: The pseudo code would be: ```for every file in dir: create img tag in html to show image``` so that if I add images to the directory, and push to server, the webpage will update to show all of the new images in the directory. Does that make sense? Thanks for all your help on this!

Comment: Try this: `files = os.listdir(os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, "static/images/"))` render this part of code in your view then iterate through them in your HTML template

Comment: Ok, cool thanks, that makes sense. Can you share how I would iterate through in the HTML though? Otherwise I'll eventually figure it out with the helpful info you've shared on view capability. Appreciate your help!